# how to perfom this query with mysql and php to export excel sheet

Tags: php, mysql

Hello there i have a problem here  , i have 2 tables one called ecom_registered_users and points  .

points tables has columns called points.customer_id which is the same for ecom_registered_users.id .

on my cms i have a page that view all users info recently i added export button to export excel sheet as a report  in case the client need it so far  , 
the problem is that i wanna get the total points for each customer i mean calculate the sum of them  , then when i export the data  i should found  the user name  , his phone number  , his email and  + another column in my excel sheet holding the total points for each user , how can i do this

here is my points table structure 
[points table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IFst.png)

and heres my ecom_registered_users

[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDFe2.png)

and heres my export code block that i should run the query

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't see your code block so I'm not sure what you've tried already, but it seems that you just need a statement like this:

```
$qry = "SELECT eru.userName, eru.userMobile, eru.userEmail, SUM(p.number)
        FROM ecom_registered_users eru 
        JOIN points p ON eru.customer_id = p.id
        WHERE eru.customer_id = /*insert customer id here*/;";
```

This query should give you the results you want for one user. If you need all users on one page you would just add GROUP BY and ORDER to the query. If you show me your code I can edit this answer to help you more.

Comment: okay but do you know hw to make this as view between the two tables the i'll select what ever i want from the view

Comment: If you want to download all the information into a CSV file and then edit out what you don't need later, you can use the following query:

`SELECT eru.userName, eru.userMobile, eru.userEmail, SUM(p.number)
        FROM ecom_registered_users eru 
        JOIN points p ON eru.customer_id = p.id
GROUP BY eru.customer_id
ORDER BY SUM(p.number)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
 session_start();


 $sql= mysql_query("$qry = "SELECT eru.userName, eru.userMobile, eru.userEmail, SUM(p.number)
    FROM ecom_registered_users eru 
    JOIN points p ON eru.customer_id = p.id
    WHERE eru.customer_id = /*insert customer id here*/;"") or die(print "Gagal Download :".mysql_error());
$columns_total = mysql_num_fields($sql);
// Get The Field Name

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$heading = mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
$output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";

// Get Records from the table

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
}
$output .="\n";
}

// Download the file

$filename = "filename.csv"; //Ur File name
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

echo $output;    
exit;
?>
```

Comment: okay seems good for only one user what if i wanna do it for all users  not only one which means ii 'll not specify an id  , how to do this

Comment: just remove > `WHERE eru.customer_id = /*insert customer id here*/`

Answer (score 0):

okay so i solve my problem here by using views like the following  :

1- view for total_points_plus (all points that have plus_minus = '+')

```
create view total_points_plus as select customer_id , sum(number) as plus from points where (customer_id in (select id from ecom_registered_users) and plus_minus = '+') group by customer_id
```

2- view for total_points_plus (all points that have plus_minus = '-')

```
create view total_points_minus as select customer_id , sum(number) as minus from points where (customer_id in (select id from ecom_registered_users) and plus_minus = '-') group by customer_id
```

3- view to make simple calculation between the above views (the grand total )

```
create VIEW total_points AS  select total_points_plus.customer_id , plus , IFNULL( minus , 0) as minus , (plus - IFNULL(minus , 0)) as grand_total from total_points_plus left join total_points_minus on total_points_plus.customer_id = total_points_minus.customer_id
```

4- get the final report  as a view also

```
create view final_report as select ecom_registered_users.userName as name  , ecom_registered_users.userEmail as email , ecom_registered_users.userMobile as mobile , total_points.grand_total as total from ecom_registered_users left join total_points on ecom_registered_users.id = total_points.customer_id
```

that's all , then in my php exporting code i do this query simple and elegant  :

```
<?php $query = "SELECT * FROM final_report " ;  ?>
```